# SEDE is not giving any results for this query only on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

When I try to run this query for my userid (`193619`) on Stack Overflow:

> http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

I get no results, however, it works just fine when I run it for Super User and Server Fault.

Comment: This is directed at [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles), 'cuz he's kind of the one working on the site :)

Comment: working on it now ... :) PostTags is empty for some reason

Comment: @waffles, cuz you broke it!! `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a dupe, the post tags table was not importing because there are 8 questions in the data dump that have no tags.

It is fixed now.